# can not setup ReactJS on mac

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start

I need to setup ReactJS on my Mac. I have `npm` version of 4.1.2 and `node` version of v7.7.4. I clone the project from Git and in the project folder trying to execute `npm install` and following `npm start`. But I get error.
I removed&uninstalled node and npm and then re-installed with homebrew, but it did not help. Here is the screen of error I get in terminal? Do you have  any idea what is the problem?

[image]

Here is my `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "viaopt",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when you run `npm start`?

Comment: you have no start script. in your package.json

Answer (score 1):

From the error you are showing I can tell that there is no **start** script in your package.json file. For `npm start` to work there should be a command under the `start` key under the `scripts` attribute in your `package.json` file.

When you run `npm start` npm looks in **package.json** and runs whatever is listed there under the `start` value.

I'm guessing you have gulp or webpack configured with your project?

Try running webpack in your terminal and see if your project fires up or smth.

Hopes this helps.
Cheers.

Comment: thank you. I also added my package.json file here. So, only thing I need to add new start script? What should be the value of 'start'?
And one more thing, is unclear for me is that, I'm not the only one cloned the project and all other developers just cloned and executed npm install and npm start and faced no error. So what may be the problem with me?

P.S I also run the 'npm install --save-dev webpack', but nothing changed.

Comment: well there is a bit much more to it than just installing webpack. I have a skeleton project which has everything preinstalled https://github.com/andrei-cacio/webpack-ready and you can start coding out of the box. If you want take a look and see how the project is configure. Also I can recommend this article on how to setup your react project http://ccoenraets.github.io/es6-tutorial-react/setup/

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to setup a new React App you can use 
[Create React App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). It will setup React / Webpack for you.

Comment: Actually, not. I'm trying to clone the project from git and run it on my laptop.

Comment: actually you are not supposed to "clone" the git repo. you are supposed to install it as a module. and run the script it provides to create the boilerplate for you. `npm i -g create-react-app` then after installing you run `create-react-app my-app` then my-app will contain all the files you need. there you will be able to npm install and npm start @user243423