# How can I set up reactjs on a Mac?

Tags: javascript, macos, reactjs, installation

Is it possible to show how to set up Reactjs on Mac. It shows multiple errors?

[image: example image]

Comment: That's not a reactjs issue, you need to change the permission on your `node_modules` folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can not setup ReactJS on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42949940/can-not-setup-reactjs-on-mac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error massage clearly indicates

> Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

So why don't you simply do it. Prepend `sudo` and execute the same command again that will enable you to run commands as the `root/Administrator`.

i.e:

```
> sudo [your command]
```